# Loss of precision casting result of SQL Server EXP to numeric

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, math

I have this c# code.

```
double x = 5.8856571269513607   
double result = Math.Exp(-x * x)
```

The value of result is 0.00000000000000090286393216423726.

I want port this over to T-SQL so I did this.

```
declare @x numeric(17,16),
        @result numeric(32,31)

set @x = 5.8856571269513607 

set @result = CAST(exp(-@x * @x) AS numeric(32,31))
```

The value of @result is 0.0000000000000009000000000000000

Any ideas why it lost the precision after the 9?

Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening converting a float value using EXP() function back into a decimal; which is limited to a maximum precision of 17 in SQL server:

From MSDN:

> Conversion of float values that use scientific notation to decimal or
> numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any value
> with precision higher than 17 rounds to zero.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173773.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck, I'm afraid. Because of how casting from float (which is what EXP() returns) to numeric, you'll always get the rounding.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx :

> "Conversion of float values that use scientific notation to decimal or
>   numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any value
>   with precision higher than 17 rounds to zero."